# How to build Java library with examples with Maven?

Tags: maven

I have a Java library with some example projects showing the usage of the library in the following project structure:

```
Project
├── examples
│   ├── ex1
│   │   ├── src
│   │   └── pom.xml      Example1 pom
│   ├── ex1
│   │   ├── src
│   │   └── pom.xml      Example2 pom
│   └── pom.xml          Examples aggregator pom
├── src
└── pom.xml              Main library pom
```

When the library is built I would like to have the examples built as well to ensure that they are in-sync with the library, but I don't want the example artifacts deployed. How Can I achieve this nicely?

I was thinking of 2 ways:

- Make the top level pom an aggregator one with 2 modules: library, examples (with examples deployment switched off). I don't like this solution because project needs to be re-organized (the library needs to go one level deeper in the hierarchy), and I would like to keep the top level pom for the main artifact of the repo.
- Add an 'exec' plugin binding to the main pom at around test/intergration-test phases that calls 'mvn compile' on the examples. This does exactly what I want, but calling maven from maven feels hacky...

So, are there any other ways to do this nicely?

Comment: The question is: What is the problem with distributing the example as usual parts?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is the following:

Make your main library pom a usual multi module parent. Make your "Examples aggregator" also a multi module parent (define the modules `example1` and `example2`) and define the skip for deployment if you like. Use in the examples the "Examples parent". 
The idea to use exec maven plugin is as you wrote `hacky`.